# Why is the query cache empty

Tags: mariadb

When I issue these commands to my MariaDB database

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';
```

The result is:

```
have_query_cache    YES 
Qcache_free_blocks  1   
Qcache_free_memory  1031304 
Qcache_hits 0   
Qcache_inserts  0   
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0   
Qcache_not_cached   0   
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0   
Qcache_total_blocks 1   
query_cache_limit   1048576 
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096    
query_cache_size    1048576 
query_cache_strip_comments  OFF 
query_cache_type    OFF 
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
```

I wonder why the `Qcache_hits` is 0 meaning in my understanding there were no cache hits were quite a number of identical queries are issued. What could prevent MariaDB from caching queries? Or do I misunderstand the `Qcache_hits` parameter?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';` and a query that failed to get into the QC.

Comment: note defaults to [off](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#query_cache_type) as its it doesn't perform well under high concurrency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Query_cache_size` is how much to allocate *at startup*.

`Query_cache_type` is `OFF` / `DEMAND` / `ON`

With `OFF` and size>0, you can turn it `ON` or `DEMAND` dynamically.

If you will never use the QC, use `OFF` and `0`.

With `OFF` and `1048576`, you get the confusing readings that you are asking about.

`OFF` is necessary for Galera Clustering.  MySQL 8 has removed it.

Consider `DEMAND` (and non-zero) and hand pick which queries to allow to be cached.  Else the QC tends to be a waste of CPU.

Comment: thanks. actually these settings is on my hoster and I'm not sure I can change them. Can I?

Comment: You can try from a MySQL Command Prompt, SET GLOBAL name=value;  To verify, SELECT @@name;  to display current Global Variable setting.

Comment: Unfortunately the hoster doesn´t allow super rights. It would make sense though as Iḿ hostinga  dataware house applicition with very little, controlled inserrts and updates and many identical selects.I guess I have to do result caching.

Answer (score 1):

@theking2

The query cache is EMPTY because you have

```
query_cache_type=OFF
```

in your configuration.